# PEP 517 Error when installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I´ve been using Pyhton 3.9.4 on mobaxterm. I am trying to install pyinstaller to create a portable exe but start the installtion keeps getting me the same Error message:

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.4.tar.gz (3.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2021.2)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (57.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->pyinstaller) (3.10.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->pyinstaller) (3.5.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyinstaller
  Building wheel for pyinstaller (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpljj4vhly
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ce8ocj14/pyinstaller_331447efec0e44d99e5342731458d786
  Complete output (19 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_bootloader
  Setting top to                           : /tmp/pip-install-ce8ocj14/pyinstaller_331447efec0e44d99e5342731458d786/bootloader
  Setting out to                           : /tmp/pip-install-ce8ocj14/pyinstaller_331447efec0e44d99e5342731458d786/bootloader/build
  Python Version                           : 3.6.8 (default, Feb 15 2019, 01:54:23) [GCC 7.4.0]
  Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /bin/gcc
  Checking size of pointer                 : 4
  Platform                                 : Cygwin-32bit detected based on compiler
  Checking for compiler flags -m32         : yes
  Checking for linker flags -m32           : yes
  Checking for library dl                  : yes
  Checking for library pthread             : yes
  Checking for library m                   : yes
  Checking for library z                   : not found
  The configuration failed
  (complete log in /tmp/pip-install-ce8ocj14/pyinstaller_331447efec0e44d99e5342731458d786/bootloader/build/config.log)
  No precompiled bootloader found. Trying to compile it for you ...
  ERROR: Failed compiling the bootloader. Please compile manually and rerun setup.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyinstaller
Failed to build pyinstaller
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyinstaller which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I am using:

- Python 3.9.4
- pip 21.1.3
- gcc 7.4.0

Thank you for your time.

Comment: might be of use - https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck/issues/343

Comment: You say you are using Python 3.9.4. But that is not what the `pip` log says. It says the version is 3.6.8. That makes one suspect that you have 2 instances of Python side-by-side and `pip` is choosing the one you don't expect.